# Return Null in jQuery method for return subgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have 2 method to get state and city from one table :

Model:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long? ParentId { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

and this is its view model

```
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long LocationId { get; set; }
```

I have 2 method to get city and state .
and with first I choose first to show first city of ID:

```
  var state = await _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();
        ViewData["State"] = state;
    

        var firstLocationId = state.First().LocationId;
        var city = await _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(firstLocationId);
        ViewData["City"] = city;
```

I user from view model. because when I use from select list, it returns null!

so after all on view this my select tag:

```
  <label class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center" for="">
                            <label> State   </label>
                            
                            <select asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="(@ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)" id="Location_Id" class="form-control">
                                <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>
                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.state)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.LocationId">@item.Title</option>

                                }
                            </select>
                            <label> City  </label>
                            <select asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="(@ViewData["city"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control ">
                                <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>
                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.city)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.LocationId && @item.Title==Title">@item.Title</option>

                                }
                            </select>
                        </label>
```

and this is my jQuery :but it does not return Sub Locations( city) and does not save  Id( I mean in location table field that :
ParentId == locationId

@section scripts
{

```
    <script>

        $("#Location_Id").change(function() {
            $("#SubLocation_Id").empty();
            $.getJSON("/UserPanel/UserInfo/GetSubGroup/" + $("Location_Id:selected").val(),
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data,
                        function() {
                            $("#SubLocation_Id").append('<option value=' + this.value + '>' + this.text + '</option>');
                        });


                });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

---

Update:
this is my get and post method:

```
[HttpGet("userInfo/first-start-userInfo/{packageId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FirstStartUserInfo(long packageId,UserPanelMenu menu=UserPanelMenu.Packages )
    {
        if (packageId <= 0) return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Home");
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!await _packageService.IsPackagePurchasedByUser(userId, packageId)) return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Home");

        var state = await _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();
        ViewData["State"] = state;


        var firstLocationId = state.First().LocationId;
        var city = await _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(firstLocationId);
        ViewData["City"] = city;
     

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost("userInfo/first-start-userInfo/{packageId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FirstStartUserInfo(CreateFirstStartUserInfoViewModel firstStartUserInfo )
    {
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();
      

        //if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(firstStartUserInfo);


        var res = await _packageService.CreateFirstStartUserInfoByUser(firstStartUserInfo, userId);
         
        return View(firstStartUserInfo);
    }
```

I fill its properties on service :
......

```
 EditFirstStartUserInfoViewModel editFirstStartUserInfo = new EditFirstStartUserInfoViewModel()
                {
                    
                    PackageId = firstStartUserInfo.PackageId,
                    Address = firstStartUserInfo.Address,
                    DayOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.DayOfBirth,
                    Goal = firstStartUserInfo.Goal,
                    Job = firstStartUserInfo.Job,
                    Marriage = firstStartUserInfo.Marriage,
                    MonthOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.MonthOfBirth,
                    Sex = firstStartUserInfo.Sex,
                    UserPackageId = userPackageId,
                    UserInfoId = await _packageRepository.GetUserInfoIdByUserPackageIdAndUserInfoSituation(userPackageId, i),
                    YearOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.YearOfBirth,
                    
                    LocationId = firstStartUserInfo.LocationId == 0 ? null : firstStartUserInfo.LocationId
```

---

Update2:
Method to get city:

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubGroup(long id)
    {
        var city =await _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(id);
        return Json(city);
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code snippet in my side and I'm afraid the issue comes from `$("Location_Id:selected").val()`, this line-code will bring me `undefined` so your ajax get request may send an error data to the server. I used `$("#Location_Id option:selected").val()` instead.

And here's my testing code -- Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["State"] = new List<State> {
                new State{ Title="state1_part1",LocationId=1},
                new State{ Title="state1_part2",LocationId=2},
                new State{ Title="state1_part3",LocationId=3},
                new State{ Title="state1_part4",LocationId=4}
            };
            ViewData["City"] = new List<City> {
                new City{ Title="city3",SubLocation_Id=2,LocationId=3},
                new City{ Title="city4",SubLocation_Id=2,LocationId=4}
            };
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult getCity(string id) {
            if (id == "1")
            {
                var citys = new List<City> {
                    new City{ Title="city1",SubLocation_Id=1,LocationId=1},
                    new City{ Title="city2",SubLocation_Id=1,LocationId=2}
                };
                return Json(citys);
            }
            else {
                var citys = new List<City> {
                    new City{ Title="city5",SubLocation_Id=3,LocationId=5},
                    new City{ Title="city6",SubLocation_Id=3,LocationId=6}
                };
                return Json(citys);
            }
           
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult savedata(HomeModelView hmv) {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult savedata2(TestViewModel tmv)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View page:

```
 @model WebApplication1.Models.HomeModelView
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="savedata" method="post">
        <label class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center" for="">
            <label> State   </label>

            <select asp-for="@Model.State.LocationId" asp-items="(@ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)" id="Location_Id" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.State.LocationId"></span>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.state)
                {
                    <option value="@item.LocationId">@item.Title</option>

                }
            </select>
            <label> City  </label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.City.LocationId" asp-items="(@ViewData["city"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control ">
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.City.LocationId"></span>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.city)
                {
                    <option value="@item.LocationId && @item.Title==Title">@item.Title</option>

                }
            </select>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <button id="test">test</button>
</div>

<script>
    $("#Location_Id").change(function () {
        $("#SubLocation_Id").empty();
        console.log($("Location_Id:selected").val());
        var selectedid = $("#Location_Id option:selected").val();
        $.getJSON("https://localhost:44386/home/getCity/" + selectedid,
            function (data) {
                console.log(data[0].title);
                $.each(data,
                    function () {
                        $("#SubLocation_Id").append('<option value=' + this.locationId + '>' + this.title + '</option>');
                    });
        });
    });

    $("#test").click(function () {
        //write the logic to obtain the title and localtion id and send them to the server
        var Title = "test_title";
        var LocationId = 1233;
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44386/home/savedata2/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                Title: Title,
                LocationId: LocationId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

viewmodel:

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public long LocationId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much with add option on jquery I can show city with change. but now mt post methid does not get this Id. just get stateId .this is my service for get :
   
                        LocationId = firstStartUserInfo.LocationId == 0 ? null : firstStartUserInfo.LocationId

Comment: Sorry for can't understand your meaning. You can show city with change means when you change the state selector, your city selector can show correct options? And your post method doesn't get id, I can't see any http post request above. Can you edit your question and add more details like error message, testing result sreenshot, the latest related code...

Comment: .yes you understand correct.I can change with change of jQuery. and can show city.  I update my question. I mean when run post method I get just stateId ,(Not cityId) both Of them are on 1 table

Comment: I tested in my side, and I find it ok to get the id in both state selector and city selector. You said that you can't get cityId but can only get stateId, I think your viewmodel lead to the issue. In your view model code snippet above, there's only location id and title, while my view model consists 2 model State and City.

Comment: because I Have one table (model Location) if parentId=null is state, if parentid==id is city. so in my view model I insert just locationId: 
   public long? LocationId { get; set; }

Comment: Hmmm, according to your description, I think you need to write the business login in your page script. Then using ajax to send post request to backend rather than a form submit. I'll test in my side.

Comment: I think I have mistake on method to get city on JSON. can you check it please .I update my question and Add it.

Comment: @hasti.au The difference between your controller method and mine is the return type, mine is JsonResult, but yours is IActionResult. And the ajax request is ok except the line-code I mentioned at first.

Comment: Yes I see and change it .and it fixes and show city on select  box. But when I call this method I see this data. is it Ok? I cant see Title of city
[{"title":"\u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0634\u0647\u0631","locationId":4},{"title":"\u0642\u0631\u0686\u06A9","locationId":5},{"title":"\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0645\u06CC\u0646","locationId":9}]

Comment: It seems an encoding issue. Did you set the encoding or decoding command in some place? Where the message you posted you got? F12 in the browser console or your controller? Anyway, you need to set charset according to the language.

Comment: yes of course . and I solve my problem too :)

Comment: Hi again. I solve all problem. but now I have a problem. If my table of location was empty I have error. How can I Prevent from this error?

Comment: @hasti.au You could set a default value for the selector just like "Please select".

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem.
first for JQUERY I had to add option as Tiny Wang " said to show city :

```
$("#Location_Id option:selected").val()
```

and for solve problem Get locationId of city , I should insert Asp-for just for city not state:

```
 <label class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center" for="">
                                <label> state </label>

                                <select    id="Location_Id" class="form-control">
                             
                                    @if (state.Any())
                                    {
                                        @foreach (var item in state )
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.LocationId">@item.Title</option>

                                        }
                                    }
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>

                                <label> City </label>
                                <select asp-for="LocationId" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control ">
                               
                                    @foreach (var item in city)
                                    {

                                        <option value="@item.LocationId ">@item.Title</option>

                                    }
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="LocationId"></span>
                            </label>
```